# Error while building maven project s4hana cloud sdk

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

with RELEASE version mentioned in archeType its giving this error

> Execution default of goal
>   com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:s4sdk-maven-plugin:2.19.1:usage-analytics
>   failed: Plugin com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:s4sdk-maven-plugin:2.19.1
>   or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect
>   dependencies at
>   com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:s4sdk-maven-plugin:jar:2.19.1 ->
>   com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:usage-analytics:jar:2.19.2-SNAPSHOT

at the time of `mvn clean install`

Comment: Kindly enhance your question with concrete steps how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error hints at a problem with your local Maven repository, which seems to contain a newer SNAPSHOT version.

Either use `mvn clean install -U` to force an update of dependencies, or delete your local `.m2` folder to download dependencies again.

Comment: Have deleted the repository.
Still getting this same error

Comment: Kindly enhance your question with *concrete* steps how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: (1). I created initial stub using
    mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-cf-tomee -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE

(2). I followed these steps 
  https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/21/step-4-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-calling-an-odata-service/
 till "Using the Destination Service on SAP Cloud Platform Cloud Foundry".

(3). mvn clean install 
  here it gives me the error

Comment: As mentioned above i tried deleting the content present inside .m2 folder.
and  repeated the same steps still its showing the same error.

Comment: Assuming that this is an issue with dependency resolution of a version range you could try to use the following code in `application/pom.xml` in the `s4sdk-maven-plugin`: `<dependencies><dependency><groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins</groupId><artifactId>usage-analytics</artifactId><version>REEASE</version></dependency></dependencies>`